# Variance of a difference in estimated proportions with trivariate discrete distributions

Tags: statistics, estimation, expectation, parameter-estimation

Let a multivariate distribution be given by $P(Y,S_1,S_2)$, where all three variables are discrete, $Y$ is multivalued, $S_1=(0,1)$ and $S_2=(0,1)$, respectively, and all may be dependent. Define the quantity $X$ as

$$X=E(Y=y|S_1=1)-E(Y=y|S_2=1).$$

I estimate X by

$$\bar{x}=\frac{1}{\sum _{i=1}^{n}S_{1i}}\sum _{i=1}^{n} I(Y_i=y)S_{1i}-\frac{1}{\sum _{i=1}^{n}S_{2i}}\sum _{i=1}^{n} I(Y_i=y)S_{2i},$$

where $I$ is the indicator function and the sum is taken over a sample of size $n$, where $i=1,..,n$. Now find the variance of $\bar{x}$, $Var(\bar{x})$, in order to finally arrive at a s.e. estimate.

I would be thankful for any advice on how to approach this problem or a solution.

Comment: If $X$ is a fixed value (given the multivariate distribution of $Y,S_1,S_2$) then its variance is zero.

Comment: I don't think it is fixed. It is a statistic like the mean and therefore should have a variance, I believe.

Comment: An expectation of a random variable with a given distribution is fixed (if it exists).  So is the difference between two expectations.

Comment: You are right! I ammended the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Did you intend $\stackrel{-}{x}=\sum_y y I(Y=y)S_1-\sum_y y I(Y=y)S_2 \, $?

Comment: Sorry, I was being imprecise again. I try to correct the estimator and hope it is clear now.